# How to stop Linux from auto-mounting USB drives?

Tags: linux, usb, backup, mount, automount

I am trying to move my main desktop from a tower system to a NUC.

Both tower and NUC are running Linux Mint (v19.3 and v20.1).

The tower had an external toaster-drive socket into which I could plug a SATA drive, to which I would write my nightly backups. The drives were EXT4 formatted, with a partition labelled "backup".

My nightly backup script would mount the partition labelled "backup" to "/mnt/backup", write the backup files, then unmount the partition. Somtime during the day, if I remembered, I'd swap the disk so that I'd maintain multiple copies.

The NUC, of course, has no such toaster-drive socket. Instead I have a Sabrent external hard drive docking station plugged into a USB port. And that is working - except...

My problem is that when I plug a drive into it, Linux is automounting the drive, under "/media/jdege/backup". I'm assuming it's using "jdege" because it's the name of the logged-in user, and "backup" because it's the label on the single partition on the disk.

My problem is that I don't want this drive to automount. I want to be able to mount it on command, then unmount it on command, and I can't do that when Linux is automounting it.

And while I don't want this drive to automount, I do want other USB drives to automount. That is, if I stick a USB stick in somewhere, I do want it to automount.

So how to I make my backup disks, and only my backup disks, not automount? (As a point of distinction, the way I'm doing things all of my backup disks, and only my backup disks, have "backup" as their partition label.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the disk an `/etc/fstab` entry, and mark it as `noauto,nofail`. The udisks2 daemon should honor this, both by disabling automounting in the desktop environment and by using your specified path.

```
UUID=abcdef /mnt/backup ext4 noauto,nofail 0 0
```

Comment: I mess about with this stuff only intermittently, on Linux, and it seems they've created a new way to handle this every couple of years.

Thanks.